# Laravel can not login user programmatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to login user automatically after registration , So I overrided `registered()` function:

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    Auth::login($user);
    logger('check', [Auth::check()]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

But user redirects to login page!  I also tried following code:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
logger('check', [Auth::check()]);
return redirect('/');
```

But same result!  Also logger logs `Auth::check()` line, the result is: `check [true]` !

Comment: `$this->guard('web')->login($user);`

Comment: @yasaryousuf ,  did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try use like that

Login and "remember" the given user...

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```

otherwise specify guard like that

```
Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);
```

third way login using id

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

Login and "remember" the given user...

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Auth::onceUsingId($user->id);
```

If logins in a user without sessions and cookies;

### Update

You need to change the redirect to be a login redirect as described here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#included-authenticating

and use the remember boolean like here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#other-authentication-methods

So your code would be just:

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```

And the redirection would be done with:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

on the models as described in the link above

Answer (score 0):

I did for my social media app a simple sign Up working with going to dashboard. This is my code. It help me previous I have the same problem but I solved this.

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'first_name'=> 'required|max:120', 
        'password'=>'required|min:4'
    ]);
       $email = $request['email'];
       $first_name = $request['first_name'];
       $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

       $user = new User();
       $user->email = $email;
       $user->first_name = $first_name;
       $user->password = $password;
       $user->save();
       Auth::login($user);
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');

  }
```

Ready simple function working for sign In.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
  { 
        $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required', 
        'password'=>'required'
        ]);
      if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password'=> $request['password']])) 
      {
          //Log in users if true e mail and pass go to dashboard
          return redirect()->route('dashboard');
      }
      return redirect()->back();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this lines of code for logging in a user

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        $user = \App\User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $this->guard('web')->login($user);
        # user logged in and remembered
        }
    else {
       # didn't match
    }
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```